# Can sudden knowledge cause health risks?

Tags: internal-consistency, science-fiction, medieval, knowledge

Well, the story goes like this: In a sci-fi space war setting, the protagonist is blasted away and somehow he crashes in a medieval-setting planet. Over there he is rescued by the princess of a warring kingdom. The protagonist's faction use a gauntlet connected to the neural system that can perform a variety of tasks, and for a handwave-y reason for now, he uses parts of his ship to build one gauntlet for the princess. And for better explanation the state of his society and why he's at war, he transfers his "general culture" knowledge via the gauntlet to her. Since she's on a society where the war norm are horses, knights, swords, bows and catapults (with a spice of magic), suddenly knowing about space stuff would leave her quite shocked, and then won't understand or even remember at first glance, but suddenly she would think in mixed terms of her and his knowledge, and even when speaking she would slip some futuristic nonsense without realizing.

So, is there any health risks involved in getting sudden knowledge? Is it safe to "implant" this knowledge quickly, or does it have to be slowly to cause no harm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TLDR: Should be shocked, but otherwise fine**

OK, so with what we could compare it?

**Having in hurry to learn to program?** May cause some headache and being generally annoyed, when everything crashes but people are generally fine.

**Discovering information that seriously change your ideological views?** Well, stress can clearly go up. Some body parts may hurt after making a series of facepalms. Nevertheless there are no medical reports showing adverse reaction to gathering worldview shattering information on taboo subjects when people become so called "red-pilled".

**LSD trip?** When the new information are no longer within realm of possibility but at least during the experience looks legit. Some people even like it. A few have really nasty "bad trip", but otherwise seem fine. Oh, and apparently people who experienced it often point it as one of the most profound events in their life and when measure very carefully their personality permanently changes, as there is a minor increase in trait openness.

Comment: +1 for "Some body parts may hurt after making a series of facepalms."

Comment: We already have stress in high performance jobs. Say you realize your sister died by sepsis and the High priest was chanting while sterilized tools could have saved her. THAT is going to be tough.

Comment: @Gustavo There is only way to feel worse, Discovering that we're not talking about some genius theory that required observations and statistical methods well beyond your era, which would absolve you. Noticing, that already before you actually had experience that dirty wounds tended to end up really badly. Oh... and you had a chat on why exactly gods are displeased as high priest chant was clearly of limited effectiveness. Nevertheless, you have not connect the dots.

Answer (score 2):

### Personality and age

There wouldn't really be any physical risks only mental ones.
To add to Shadow1024's answer you might want to consider what kind of a personality this princess has. People react differently to new information from person to person. One might simply not believe what they see and reject it outright while someone else will accept it straight away.

Most people will need some time to come to grips with world-view changing information.
Also, age tends to have an influence on someone's willingness to accept new views. The older people are the more they cling to their old beliefs.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the opposite might happen. Learning new information releases endorphins, which make you feel good. Learning a great deal of information may put the princess in a state of euphoria for several hours. However, being exposed to such high levels of endorphins can desensitize your brain, which means that normal activities would no longer feel (as) good. Depression may follow, and an instinct to use the gauntlet again since it is the only thing that makes her feel good any more, but she already knows everything it can teach so even that loses it's allure.

Until she realizes the thrill of life threatening situations. She becomes addicted to danger. She just doesn't feel alive unless she's walking away from an explosion with her enemies roasting inside the expanding fireball of death behind her.

But then all of the enemies are destroyed, and she once again has nothing left, nothing but the hollowness inside of her.